# ElasticSearch Modified Analyzer not working [Stopwords]

Tags: elasticsearch, stop-words

I added the following to my elasticsearch.yml

```
# Index Settings
index:
  analysis:
    analyzer:
      # set standard analyzer with no stop words as the default for both indexing and searching
      default:
        type: standard
        stopwords: _none_
```

Now I did the following:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=default' -d 'this is a test'
```

and still got:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I want all the words to be in there! Not that I am running elasticsearch via:

```
sudo /usr/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.90.0/bin/service/elasticsearch64 restart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this setting instead, (instead of *none*, use an empty string in the stopwords section)

```
# Index Settings
index:
  analysis:
    analyzer:
      # set standard analyzer with no stop words as the default for both indexing and searching
      default:
        type: custom
        tokenizer: standard
        filter: [standard,lowercase]
```

Please note that you need to restart elasticsearch service once you make this change.

Comment: sudo /usr/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.90.0/bin/service/elasticsearch64 restart
Stopping ElasticSearch...
Stopped ElasticSearch.
Starting ElasticSearch...
Waiting for ElasticSearch......
running: PID:14633
[ec2-user@ip-10-169-4-9 config]$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=default' -d 'this is a test'
{"tokens":[{"token":"test","start_offset":10,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":4}]}[ec2-user@ip-10-169-4-9 config]$

Comment: I'm sorry, the analyzer type has to be custom in this case (if you want to change the default behaviour). There you can specify required tokenizers and filters. Please see my edited answer. In the filter the stop has been removed. The default standard analyzer comes with standard, lowercase and stop filters.